# How to find maximum historical value but less than current today's value in pandas for each user?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a user journey table and want to get the max date when a user was seen as of todays date. This is my table:

```
notification_ date | user_id | login_date 
2020-01-01         | 1       | null
2020-03-01         | 1       | 2020-03-05
2020-03-10         | 1       | null
2020-03-11         | 1       | 2020-03-11
```

Now, I want to add a column that tells me how many days ago from each notification_date the user was active on like this:

```
notification_ date | user_id | login_date  | last_active_date
2020-01-01         | 1       | null        | null
2020-03-01         | 1       | 2020-03-05  | null
2020-03-10         | 1       | null        | 2020-03-05
2020-03-11         | 1       | 2020-03-11  | 2020-03-11
```

How would I get the "last_active_date" column correctly in the most efficient way in pandas for each **user id**?

Comment: why is the last active date on the last row `2020-03-11` and not `2020-03-05`? or, why is the last active date on the second row empty and not `2020-03-05`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'notification': ['2020-01-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-03-10', '2020-03-11','2020-03-15','2020-03-17'],
        'user_id': [1,1,1,1,2,2],
        'login_date':[np.nan,"2020-03-05",np.nan,"2020-03-11",np.nan,'2020-03-15']
        }
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[["notification", "login_date"]] = df[["notification", "login_date"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)
#Added groupby with `user_id` and Shift column in pandas dataframe down by one
df['last_active_date'] = df.groupby('user_id')['login_date'].shift(+1)
#Add Flag to check whether notification data and login data are equal or not
df['Flag'] = df.notification.eq(df.login_date).view('i1')
#If Flag==1, the copy `notification` date to `last_active_date`, otherwise no change in date
df['last_active_date'] = np.where(((df['Flag'] == 1)),df['notification'],df['last_active_date'] )
#Del FLag Col
del df['Flag']
df
```

Output-

```
    notification    user_id login_date  last_active_date
0   2020-01-01         1    NaT            NaT
1   2020-03-01         1    2020-03-05     NaT
2   2020-03-10         1    NaT         2020-03-05
3   2020-03-11         1    2020-03-11  2020-03-11
4   2020-03-15         2    NaT            NaT
5   2020-03-17         2    2020-03-15     NaT
```